# pytest - how can i test a try and except code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

so i have this line of code, how can i test the try and except part using pytest ? i want to test if i input a string the test will notice it and response saying wrong input and if i input a integer the test will passed. help me please thanks

```
def add_member(self):
        p_name = input("Enter your project name: ")
        i = 0
        participant_name=[]
        role=[]
        while True:
            try:
                many = int(input ("How many member do you want to add ?: "))
                while i< many:
                    i+=1
                    participant_name.append(str(input("Enter name: "))  )
                    role.append(str(input("Enter role: ")))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Insert an integer")
        self.notebook.add_member(p_name, participant_name, role)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have too much code in the `try` block. The only thing there that raises a `ValueError` (that your error message accurately addresses) is the call to `int` on the first line. Second, don't hard-code `input` in code you plan to test; instead, pass a second argument that *defaults* to `input`, but allows you to provide a deterministic function for testing.

```
def add_member(self, input=input):
    p_name = input("Enter your project name: ")
    participant_names = []
    roles = []
    while True:
        try:
            many = int(input("How many member do you want to add? "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter an integer")

    for i in range(many):
        name = input("Enter name: ")
        role = input("Enter role: ")
        participant_names.append(name)
        roles.append(role)
    self.notebook.add_member(p_name, participant_names, roles)

def make_input(stream):
    def _(prompt):
        return next(stream)
    return _

def test_add_member():
    x = Foo()
    x.add_member(make_input(["Manhattan", "0"])
    # assert that x.notebook has 0 participants and roles

    x = Foo()
    x.add_member(make_input(["Omega", "ten", "2", "bob", "documentation", "alice", "code"]))
    # assert that self.notebook has bob and alice in the expected roles
```

Better yet, though, the code that asks for input should probably be entirely separate from the this method, which should simply take a project name and a set of participants
and their roles (*not* two separate lists). That set could be a list of tuples, or a dict, but it should be something that doesn't allow a mismatch between the names of each participant and their roles.

```
def add_member(self, name, participants):
    self.notebook.add(name, [x[0] for x in participants], [x[1] for x in participants])

def test_add_member():
    x = Foo()
    x.add_member("Manhattan", [("bob", "documentation"), ("alice", "code")])
    # same assertion as before
```